# How do remove the pre-selected Tab indicator from Materializecss?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using the **tab** in Materilizecss to design the Navigation tabs in my web app.

By default, the first tab is selected. This is **indicated** by an underlining line under the first tab, as seen in the picture below.
[image]

By default, I do **NOT** want **ANY** of the tab to be preselected! To be clear, I do not want any of the tabs to have **any** underlining by default as seen in the image below. 
[image]

I want the tabs to be unselected by default until a user chooses one of the tabs, only then will that tab get an underlining line under it.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation about removing the default selected tabs/underlining.

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remove your border bottom :

```
.target {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

And to bring up with hover :

```
.target:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```